# Can I list my reasons using multiple sentences and then write "therefore" to tell the result?

Tags: adverbs

**Example 1**

> The test was difficult for middle schoolers like me. When I was answering the test questions, some people were making noises. Before the test, I was not able to sleep well, so I felt so sleepy during the test. **Therefore**, I got a poor grade on that test.

Can I list my reasons using multiple sentences and then write "therefore" to tell the result like my example 1?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a perfectly valid and usual structure.

It might be better n\to avoid the repletion of "*so*" in the third sentence.

Comment: Although you could use an introductory sentence such as "There were several reasons why I did badly..."